# Picture Password Source

Tags: c#, windows, authentication, passwords, login-control

Is it possible to recreate the picture password as a login mechanism for your .NET application? Or is there some law stating it cant be done because you'll get sued?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/12/16/signing-in-with-a-picture-password.aspx

Comment: It depends on soo many variables (your country's local laws, purpose of the face-templates database, etc, etc) it's almost impossible for us to determine whether it's legal or not.

Comment: Is that article correct? Under "Security and gesture count" They give the formula for the permutations of 1 to n lowercase letters as `sum(26^n)`, shouldn't that be `sum(26^i)`? Then the next sentence only does `26^8` rather than the full sum allowing for less characters. I see a lot of problems there anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Microsoft seem to have a patent for this approach in the USA at least: http://patft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=8,024,775.PN.&OS=PN/8,024,775&RS=PN/8,024,775 , so depending where you're based you might run into legal problems.